# how to access an element of array whose index is of long type

Tags: java, arrays, types

Whenever I try to access an element from an array that has an index of long data type, I am unable to do so.

I need to obtain the character presented at a certain index to compare with another character.

I have tried with the `getChar()` of Array class and tried to get the character using the index. Below are the snippets I tried.

Trial 1

```
for (long i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c = Array.getChar(newArray, i);
    if (c != 'a') {
    } else {
        ctr++;
    }
}
```

Trial 2

```
for (long i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c = newArray[(int) i];
    if (c != 'a') {
    } else {
        ctr++;
    }
}
```

Expected - I should get the character for the index I was seeking.

Error - Possible loss of precision.

Comment: Array indexes in Java are of `int` type, not `long`. `Array::getChar` takes an `int` as a parameter for the index, not a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Max size of arrays in java is Integer.MAX_VALUE-2 (in Java 8 Open JDK):

// don't compile

```
Object oArray[] = new Object[Long.MAX_VALUE];
```

// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

```
Object oArray[] = new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

```
Object oArray[] = new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1];
```

// That's ok

```
Object oArray[] = new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2];
```

Then, long index type is no appropriated, because you cannot get index positions after the max value - 2.

If you want create a 'in memory' storage of chars with a size great than Integer limit, you may create a instance of Map:

```
Map<Long, Character> map = new HashMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your Array can never be bigger then `Integer.MAX_VALUE-2`, it is enough to access it via an integer, not a long.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     c = newArray[i];
     if (c != 'a') {
     } else {
         ctr++;
     }
}
```